# Set JVM parameters in JUnit test extending AbstractJUnit38SpringContextTests

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have some tests extending the class AbstractJUnit38SprintContextTests, initializing the application Spring context, inject input and checks outputs (mainly messages, states and modes).

I need to test the application behavior with two different values passed in the java command-line running the application (-Dparam=true/false).

How can I set this parameters in the JUnit process ?

Edit : simple solution

```
public void test() {
System.setProperty("param", "true")
ApplicationContext context = new ClasspathXmlApplicationContext(file)
 ... asserts ...
}
```

Comment: What is using the system property? Is it used by the Spring context or only by your code?

Comment: The application is launched by a simple main in a class Launcher with the Spring context initialisation in it. In JUnit tests, we don't call the Launcher class, only the Spring init with annoation @ContextConfiguration. I need to have the -Dparam set before the Spring init. The static block with System.setProperty() in each JUnit class does not work because I need to test different param values and only the last class loaded in classloader will be taken into account.

Comment: Simple solution, not using the AbstractJunit38SpringContextTests facilities, doing the old way ...